# Epitome of the entire drama

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What do we mean by the word "epitome"?

Here is the sentence

"The epitome of the entire drama is Artificial intelligence.."

The above sentence is from the book 
AI - the very idea
By Sir John Haugeland

Also, examples in which the given word is used....

Comment: Have you looked it up in a dictionary?

Comment: Please look in a dictionary for a definition and examples. If you still need help, you would need to provide more context from the source, and explain why you had difficulty applying the definition to the sentence.

Comment: Epitome is given as personification, I  failed to relate it. Can you any example where this word is used ....so I can get it more clear

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/epitome To be honest, I can't see how either definition fits Alka's sentence.

Comment: Really need to see more context.

Answer (score 1):

> For the current generation has seen a sudden and brilliant flowering
>   in the philosophy/science of the mind; by now not only psychology but
>   also a host of related disciplines are in the throes of a great
>   intellectual revolution.  And the epitome of the entire drama is
>   *Artificial Intelligence*, the exciting new effort to make computers think. [Google Books]

Thus "drama" is used in a metaphorical sense.  And it appears to be saying that AI is the best possible example of this revolution.